# CoreNFC - Empty NDEF after upgrade to iOS16

Tags: ios, nfc, core-nfc

I've just updated to iOS 16, and all of a sudden the same code I used in iOS 15 is now reading `ndefMessage` as `nil` in the `didDetect` callback. I can't find anything online regarding what in iOS 16 would cause this, has anyone seen anything similar?

When I scan the same tag on Android, or use the NFC Tools app on iOS, I can read the tag NDEF fine. It seems that just my code seems to have been affected by the update...

**UPDATE 1:**  I have put the **same** code onto my iOS 15.6 device, and it works perfectly. It seems to me that this is an iOS 16 bug.

Here's what I have:

```
func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCNDEFTag]) {
    print("did detect")
    let str: String = nfcWriteContent
    if (tags.count > 1) {
        let retryInterval = DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(500)
        session.alertMessage = "too_many_nfc_detected".localized()
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + retryInterval, execute: {
            session.restartPolling()
        })
        return
    }
    
    let tag = tags.first!
    
    print("reading...")
    tag.readNDEF(completionHandler: {(ndefMessage: NFCNDEFMessage?, error: Error?) in
        var res = ""
        
        if (ndefMessage == nil) {
            // EVERY NFC SCAN ALWAYS FALLS IN HERE NOW
            // WHEN SCANNING THE SAME TAG ON ANDROID, NDEF CONTENT IS PROPERLY RETURNED
            print("empty tag")
        } else {
            print (ndefMessage!.records.count)
            for payload in ndefMessage!.records {
                if (payload.payload.count == 0) {
                    continue
                }
                res += (String.init(data: payload.payload.advanced(by: 1), encoding: .utf8) ?? "Format not supported")
            }
        }
        
        session.alertMessage = "tag_successfully_read".localized()
        session.invalidate()
        print("read \(res)")
    })
            
}
```

Comment: Any particular Tag Type, have you tried any other Tag Type?

Comment: @Andrew I'm using NFC Forum Type 2 Tag, no I haven't tried any other tag type yet (don't have any others accessible at the moment). It's super strange because I've been using these Type 2 tags all day with this code, but I decided to update to iOS 16 earlier and now the ndef is always read as nil. NFC write seems to work fine however...

Comment: @Andrew check my edit - looks like this is an iOS 16 bug

Comment: Hey @sparkhead95 , I'm seeing the same with NTAG 213. I discovered it because some of my customers are complaining. `tag.readNDEF` returns "Tag not connected" as error. However NTAG 216 is working fine for me...

Comment: I tried the async await API last night but that also has the bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got feedback from an Apple engineer. The [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app) runs fine on iOS 16. You are missing out that you are not connected to the tag:

```
try await ndefReaderSession?.connect(to: tag)
let message = try await tag.readNDEF()

or

ndefReaderSession?.connect(to: tag) { error in
    //call tag.readNDEF here   
}
```

Comment: Something to note - I had my entitlements file like this when I deployed to TestFlight, and the upload failed, warning me that the NFC entitlements weren't correct. I had to *remove* NDEF to fix it. Perhaps this is linked...

Comment: Alright, you are right. That was not the correct answer @sparkhead95 . I saw the warning as well. I found the error now and adapted the answer.

Comment: I am doing the same in my code in my question - i connect at the start, then called tag.readNDEF. Or did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: Where? I don't see the connect call in your code @sparkhead95

Comment: Oh you're right! I also have some NFC write code (that does connect) and I was looking at that instead by accident. Thanks for your help! Interesting that I didn't need to connect in iOS 15.